# How to predict number from a set of data?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, random, nearest

I have 2 sets of data. For example,

```
a={1,2,3,4,5}
b={5,4,3,2,1}
data= MapThread[List,{a,b}];
p = Predict[Rule @@@ ta12, 
  Method -> {"NearestNeighbors", Range[1,5]}]
```

I expect to have a set of {1,3},{3,5}.. something like this.
Unfortunately, I got an error that the format is incorrect.
How Should I fix it?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost got it right...

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
b = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
data = MapThread[List, {a, b}];
p = Predict[Rule @@@ data, Method -> "NearestNeighbors"]
```

Now you can call the function p, so that p[1] gives 4.5 and p[2] gives 3.5. To get all the values over the range 1 to 5:

```
p /@ Range[1, 5]
```

If you want the answer in {x,y} pairs:

```
Thread[{a, p /@ a}]
```

Comment: I still get only one set of numbers not {x, y} like this. Or I miss something here.

Comment: You can get {x,y} pairs easily enough as in the update...

Comment: Thank you very much